# What does a curve with unbounded acceleration tells about its shape?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and assume that $c : \mathbb{R} \to M$ is a smooth curve. I am work on a research problem where
$$\left\|\dfrac{\nabla}{dt}c'\right\|\to \infty.$$

What can I conclude about the shape of the curve?

Alternatively, given an extra condition on the problem, if the acceleration blows up, then for a smooth vector field $\nu$ along the curve, there is $t_0 > 0$ such that for all $t>t_0$,
$$g(\nabla_{\nu}\nu,\dfrac{\nabla}{dt} c') < 0,$$
does this imply something obvious?

Comment: Clearly you can reparameterize any noncompact curve to get its acceleration to be unbounded, so all you can say is that it is not defined on a compact interval. Since your curve is defined on the real number line, I don't see anything else.

Comment: The second condition, since it only involves a vector field $v$ defined along the curve, can surely be satisfied by one tangent to the curve, reducing the problem to $M=\mathbb{R}$, where it is clearly satisfied for any curve, with some choice of $v$ growing rapidly and pointing the other direction.